# Cant access WAMP over LAN

Tags: apache, wamp, lan

I have read many posts here and many tutorials as well.. and for some reason..  I just cant get access to my WAMP install/pages/content from other machines on the network?

WAMP 2.4 (still) :)

Here is what I have tried so far:

WAMP install machine IP:  192.168.1.121

- I have enabled/disbaled Windows Firewall on the WAMP install machine (completely for testing)
- I have created a an INBOUND rule allowing  (TCP, on PORT 80, private option selected only, also tried to check public)

Apache httpd.config:

- Listen 192.168.1.121:80
- Listen 80

Then a bit below:

- Order Deny,Allow
- Allow from 127.0.0.1
- Allow from ::1
- Allow from localhost
- Allow from 192.168.1.101
- Allow from all

Complete:

```
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    # onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    # Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 192.168.1.101
    Allow from all  

    </Directory>
```

I my Apache httpd-vhosts.conf file I have (outside of some other default and test entries) the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@BarBot.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/barbot/"
    ServerName BarBot
    ErrorLog "logs/BarBot-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/BarBot-access.log" common
    <directory "c:/wamp/www/barbot/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Require all granted 
        
    #Deny from all
    #AllowOverride All
    #Allow from 127.0.0.1
    #Require all granted
    #Require ip 192.168.1
    #Require ip 192.168.1:80
        
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I grabbed a netbook I had laying around.. plugged it into my network..

loaded up browser and went to:

192.168.1.121
as well as
192.168.1.121:80
192.168.1.121:80/barbot

I will either get:

- timed out message on browser..
  or more recently
- Not found: The requested URL /barbot was not found..etc..etc..

At this point I am lost..   I dont even have a direction to pursue or test with?

I have also tried to toggle putting WAMP online/offline..  neither state seemed to make a difference?

What am I missing here?  What things can I test out?  And is there a way to check on things?  Logs? Errors?  Something that will give me direction?  Or help get direction at least?)

Update:

Second PC -

IP:  192.168.1.101

I can PING the 192.168.1.121 machine just fine.. never misses a packet.

---

Final State:

Something is 'working', but must be configured somehow/somewhere?

When I attempt to open:  192.168.1.121:80/barbot (WAMP machine)  I get a NOT FOUND (404) page...

If I try to go to say... 192.168.1.121:8080  (I get Unable to Connect page/message)..

Comment: Did you config network IPs? Does your second device have the same IP range?

Comment: @FarZanTakhsha
Second PC IP:  192.168.1.101

Configure network IP's how?  (Im not clear what you are referring to?)

I can ping 192.168.1.121 from 192.168.1.101 and do not lose packets. (all successful)

Comment: Your network configuration is OK. Don't touch it! Click on WAMP tiny icon on taskbar and in menu click "Put Online". Check again on another machines

Comment: It already is 'Online' unfortunately..

Comment: Open main config file (httpd.conf) and search for keyword "Require". check all of them to be "Require all granted". (after any changes, restart wamp).

Comment: Is that the correct syntax for 2.4? (but I do have Require all granted all over)

Comment: I updated original message with the final state of things

Comment: Please check these lines in your httpd.conf file, and try again: 
Listen 0.0.0.0:80  
Listen [::0]:80  
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080  
Listen [::0]:8080  
ServerName <your ip>

Comment: @FarZanTakhsha

As soon as I add these lines: Listen 0.0.0.0:80   WAMP wont restart (stays organge. never green)

Comment: Anyone?  Ideas on Why 192.168.1.121:80/barbot (or anything on 192.168.1.121) says NOT FOUND...  but other ports Time Out/Cant connect?   Seems like it sees the IP 192.168.1.121.. but not seeing any directories? (or something?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224614/discussion-between-whispers-and-farzan-takhsha).